# Cantidad de ocurrencias de la subsecuencia [1,2,3] en un vector

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de implementar este ejercicio pero no tengo idea de como empezar; alguien podria sugerirme algun camino?

PRE: Recibe un vector de enteros (formado únicamente por los números 1, 2 y 3) y su largo

POS: Devuelve la cantidad de ocurrencias de la subsecuencia [1,2,3] (elementos consecutivos en la secuencia) en ese vector. 
     Se deben tomar en cuenta las secuencias como 1,2,2,3 o 1,1,2,2,2,2,3,1,2,2,3, etc., donde pueden aparecer varios números 1 juntos, varios 2 y varios 3.

Ejemplo 1
Entrada: [1,2,3,1,2,2,3]
Salida: 2

Ejemplo 2
Entrada [1,2,2,2,2,2,3,1,2,3]
Salida: 2
*/

```
int ocurrencias123Repetidos(int* vector, int largo) {
int contUno = 0;
int contDos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++)
{
    if (vector[i] == 1 && vector[i] < vector[i + 1] && vector[i + 1] != 3 && contUno == 0) {
        contUno++;
    }
    if (vector[i] == 2 && vector[i] < vector[i + 1] && contUno == 1) {
        contUno++;
    }
    else if (vector[i + 1] == 1) {
        contUno = 0;
    }
    if (contUno == 2) {
        contDos++;
        contUno = 0;
    }
}
return contDos;
```

}

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Hola gbianchi; gracias por tu comentario. Lo tendr[e en cuenta. Disculpas que soy nuevo en esto!

Comment: La voya reformular

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tengo es:

1. Necesitamos declarar dos variables, digamos `cont` y `key`, inicializadas en cero, una para contar las ocurrencias de la secuencia completa, que será el valor de retorno, y otra para controlar la secuencia mientras se va dando, que crezca mientras la secuencia se va dando correctamente o que se reinicie si hubo un fallo en la misma.
2. Recorremos el vector de forma normal.
3. Si `key=0`, debemos buscar **1**, si aparece **1** `key` se incrementará en uno.
4. Si `key=1` significa que ya encontramos la primera ocurrencia de **1**, ahora nos toca buscar **2**, ignorando los **1** y reiniciando `key` si aparece **3**.
5. Si `key=2` nos toca buscar **3**, debemos ignorar **2** y reiniciar `key` si aparece **1**, adicionalmente si aparece **3**, aumentamos `cont` y también reiniciamos `key` para realizar otra busqueda.

Reiniciar `key` implica que hubo un fallo en la secuencia y debemos empezar de nuevo la busqueda, cuando `key=2` y se encuentra un **3**, se puede decir que se ha completado la secuencia, entonces incrementamos `cont` en uno y empezamos otra busqueda, para ello también será necesario reiniciar `key`.

Utilizando la clase `vector`, la forma de aplicar lo anterior sería:

```
  int ocurrencias123Repetidos(std::vector<int> vector) {
    //nos servirá para mantener la secuencia
    int key = 0;

    //contará las ocurrencias
    int cont = 0;

    for (int valor : vector) {
        if (key == 0) {
            //si key=0 debemos buscar uno
            if (valor == 1)
                key++;
        }
        else if (key == 1) {
            //key=1 significa que ya encontramos la primera ocurrencia de 1
            //ahora nos toca buscar 2, ignorando los 1 o reiniciando key si
            //aparece 3.
            if (valor == 2)
                key++;
            else if (valor == 3)
                key=0;
            else;
        }
        else if (key == 2) {
            //nos toca buscar 3, debemos ignorar 2 y reiniciar key si
            //aparece 1, adicionalmente si aparece 3, aumentamos cont
            //y también reiniciamos key
            if (valor == 3) {
                key = 0;
                cont++;
            }
            else if (valor == 1)
                key = 0;
            else;
        }
        else;
    }
    return cont;
}
```

Comment: En general, tratamos de no contestar preguntas que son ejercicios donde no se demuestra haber intentado hacer nada.

Comment: Si pensé en eso, por eso hice la explicación e intenté usar otros argumentos para la función, pero bueno, tal vez no sea suficiente.

Comment: Hola! HE reformulado la pregunta en:https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/342703/cantidad-de-ocurrencias-de-la-subsecuencia-1-2-3-en-un-vector-version-2 .  @gbianchi, soy nuevo, no debes ser duro con los novatos. Debes tener empatía. Saludos!

Comment: @JuanPabloGonzález no somos duros, pero hay reglas y en general cuando uno entra a un lugar nuevo, suele leerlas o preguntar cuales son. Cerre tu nueva pregunta, porque volver a preguntar lo mismo no esta permitido (por ejemplo). Te recomiendo leer el [tour] que explica como funciona el sitio.

Comment: @JuanPabloGonzález ¿ No comprendes los conceptos de **normas, reglas y leyes** ? Yo creía que eran universales :-/

Comment: ¿ Predicar con el ejemplo ? ¿ Como ? La pregunta estaba mal formulada, y se cierra. Solo tienes que arreglarla para que se vuelva a abrir. Y aquí no solemos faltar al respeto a nadie

Comment: No estaba mal formulada; FALTABA INFORMACION; no era más fácil "cortar" la respuesta en "Vuelva a editarla, proporcione más información y explique lo que desea hacer el código; comprendemos que ud es nuevo en el foro". En caso contrario, si no me atengo a las reglas AHI SI, que cierren lo que entiendan pertinente. ¿Tan difícil es eso de comprender? Pedagogía 0 el moderador. Primero se saca amarilla, no roja directa (esto no fue una "plancha"), fue un "foult". ¿Me expliqué?

Comment: De todos modos ya pude resolver la duda y quédese tranquil@ que ya entendí perfectamente las reglas. Gracias por su tiempo @Trauma.

Comment: No entiendo el porqué te enfadas. Aquí todos empezamos de novatos, sin tener mucha idea ... y fuimos aprendiendo. A mi me llegaron a decir que mi pregunta tenía *verborrea*. La edité, la arreglé, ... y aquí sigo.

Comment: @JuanPabloGonzález voy a hacer caso omiso a tu falta de respeto (la cual es causal de baneo en el sitio). Fijate que aca no hay amarillas o rojas.. y cerrar y abrir preguntas es algo trivial para los moderadores (y en casos de preguntas que reciben respuestas rapidamente solemos cerrarlas hasta que sean mejoradas). Si en lugar de enojarte y critircar, leyeras y preguntaras, no tendrias ningun problema... Y faltar el respesto a alguien que trato de ayudarte, no es para nada agradable. Y ojala pudieras decirme en que parte de mi mensaje fui mal educado.

Comment: @JuanPabloGonzález Tene en cuenta que soy moderador del sitio porque la comunidad (no el sitio) me voto para que lo sea.. Y por algo sera...

Comment: @Trauma Mire, aquellos que le dicen eso, están siendo pedantes. Cada ser humano es único e irrepetible; no vengo aquí a dar cátedra de nada a nadie; me enojé pues la actitud del moderador no me pareció para nada correcta (y menos de un argentino que viven presumiendo acá y en la China). Yo vengo a aprender no a que me cierren la puerta. ¿Sabe como se llama todo esto? INTELIGENCIA EMOCIONAL. No muchos la tienen. Lo que logró el moderador, es quebrar mi inteligencia emocional por su carencia de empatía.

Comment: Pufff ... en mi pueblo, tambien se le llama `tener la piel fina`. Es cuestión de punto de vista.

Comment: Desde luego, faltando el respeto a la gente, tengo comprobado que no se consigue mucho. Ni aquí, ni en Argentina, ni en la China.

Comment: @JuanPabloGonzález borre tu comentario porque las faltas de respeto a otros usuarios no estan permitidas, y no lo voy a soportar. Te pido por favor que te tomes unos minutos para respirar y entender que un cierre no es tan terrible como lo pensas, es como funciona el sitio.

Comment: @JuanPabloGonzález pero que tal si haces una [pregunta en el Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/) y discutimos lo que te molesta, tenemos como regla el respeto y creo que pasastes el limite , ademas en este sitio la cultura es una , todos somos stackoverflow en Español

Comment: @JackNavaRow y tu quien sos? El abogado? Métete en tus asuntos!

Comment: en este sitio no hay abogados, funcionamos como comunidad y tratamos de ayudar uno con otros y si alguien tiene una diferencia la discutimos en meta, para eso te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Comment: @JackNavaRow Ya lo vi; a mi no me lo digas, díselo al moderador; lo recomendó después de su fea actitud.