# Cantidad de ocurrencias de la subsecuencia [1,2,3] en un vector (version 2)

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de implementar este ejercicio pero no tengo idea de como empezar; alguien podria sugerirme algun camino?

PRE: Recibe un vector de enteros (formado únicamente por los números 1, 2 y 3) y su largo

POS: Devuelve la cantidad de ocurrencias de la subsecuencia [1,2,3] (elementos consecutivos en la secuencia) en ese vector. 
     Se deben tomar en cuenta las secuencias como 1,2,2,3 o 1,1,2,2,2,2,3,1,2,2,3, etc., donde pueden aparecer varios números 1 juntos, varios 2 y varios 3.

Ejemplo 1
Entrada: [1,2,3,1,2,2,3]
Salida: 2

Ejemplo 2
Entrada [1,2,2,2,2,2,3,1,2,3]
Salida: 2
*/

```
int ocurrencias123Repetidos2(int* vector, int largo) {
    int contUno = 0;
    int contDos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++)
    {
        if (vector[i] == 1 && vector[i] < vector[i + 1] && vector[i + 1] != 3 && contUno == 0) {
            contUno++;
        }
        if (vector[i] == 2 && vector[i] < vector[i + 1] && contUno == 1) {
            contUno++;
        }
        else if (vector[i + 1] == 1) {
            contUno = 0;
        }
        if (contUno == 2) {
            contDos++;
            contUno = 0;
        }
    }
    return contDos;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int total_secuencias = 0;
int actual = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++)
{
  if( vector[i] == actual ) continue;

  if( vector[i] == actual+1 )
  {
    if( actual == 2 )
    {
      total_secuencias++;
      actual = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      actual++;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    actual = 0;
  }
}
```

El bucle comprueba si el número actual se corresponde con el número que le precedía o si es superior en una unidad. Si es así pasa a buscar el siguiente número de la secuencia... cuando ha completado una secuencia incrementa el contador.

Si se rompe la secuencia, por ejemplo si tras un `2` se encuentra un `1`, se reinicia la búsqueda de la secuencia.

Como tenemos que garantizar que haya al menos un `1`, inicializamos `actual` en `0`. El bucle entonces buscará o `0` o `1`... el primero no le encontrará nunca pero si localizará el primer `1` que haya. Después, cuando en `actual` haya un `1`, el algortimo buscará `1` y `2` ... si encuentra `2` pasará a buscar `2` y `3` y al encontrar el `3` incrementará el total

Comment: Excelente!!! Gracias, se entendió

Answer (score 0):

Me tomó tiempo entender el código, pero parece que funciona bien, sin embargo, quiero indicar algunos detalles.

1. En cada iteración en el bloque `for` se comparan valores en la ubicación `i` e `i+1`, el detalle es que llegando a la última repetición, se estaría leyendo una ubicación en memoria que no le pertenece al vector, es decir, si tu vector tiene 10 elementos y estás en la última ubicación i.e. `i=9`, tu código también leerá la ubicación `i+1` i.e. `i=10`, elemento que ya no le pertenece al vector, esto no te da fallos en la compilación ya que [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) no verifica límites, pero podría darte resultados erroneos, tal vez poco probables pero probables al fin y al cabo, aquí me explico.

Supongamos que este es tu vector:

```
[1,2,2,2,2,2,3,1,2]
```

la cantidad de veces que aparece la secuencia es 1 obviamente, pero ¿que pasa si en la siguiente ubicación fuera del vector hay un 3?, en realidad en esta ubicación podría haber cualquier valor ya que no se inicializó.

```
[1,2,2,2,2,2,3,1,2] 3 
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Ya que tu código esta leyendo en esta ubicación, considerará este valor y por tanto el programa te dirá que se encontró la secuencia 2 veces. Como dije, en esta ubicación podría estar cualquier valor, es poco probable encontrar un 3 (es por eso que los resultados en general son correctos), pero igual es probable.

Entonces, la solución a esto es simplemente disminuir el rango de repeticiones:

```
for (int i = 0; i < largo-1; i++)
```

2. El condicional:

```
if (vector[i] == 1 && vector[i] < vector[i + 1] && vector[i + 1] != 3 && contUno == 0)
```

puede simplificarse a

```
if (vector[i] == 1 && vector[i + 1]==2 && contUno == 0)
```

y tal vez:

```
if (vector[i] == 2 && vector[i] < vector[i + 1] && contUno == 1)
```

a:

```
if (vector[i] == 2 && vector[i + 1]==3 && contUno == 1)
```

Fuera de todo esto, el código parece estar bien, si nos nos preocupa el rendimiento pues es suficiente con que trabaje bien.

Aprovecho para copiar la propuesta que te hice en el primer post, adaptada a tus argumentos, que no necesita leer en la ubicación `i+1`:

```
int ocurrencias123Repetidos(int* vector, int largo) {
    //nos servirá para mantener la secuencia
    int key = 0;

    //contará las ocurrencias
    int cont = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < largo; ++i) {
        if (key == 0) {
            //si key=0 debemos buscar uno
            if (vector[i] == 1)
                key++;
        }
        else if (key == 1) {
            //key=1 significa que ya encontramos la primera ocurrencia de 1
            //ahora nos toca buscar 2, ignorando los 1 o reiniciando key si
            //aparece 3.
            if (vector[i] == 2)
                key++;
            else if (vector[i] == 3)
                key=0;
            else;
        }
        else if (key == 2) {
            //nos toca buscar 3, debemos ignorar 2 y reiniciar key si
            //aparece 1, adicionalmente si aparece 3, aumentamos cont
            //y también reiniciamos key
            if (vector[i] == 3) {
                key =0;
                cont++;
            }
            else if (vector[i] == 1)
                key=0;
            else;
        }
        else;
    }
    return cont;
}
```

Si estás usando [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), creo que lo más recomendable sería usar la clase `vector`, el código lo dejé en tu primer [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/342400/154404).

Comment: Muchas gracias por todos tus aportes!! HE logrado que funcione! Tome un poco de cada uno de sus aportes! Saludos!!!